# SQL Server - Update nullable int field of a big table to have a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, default, nullable

I have a big table (millions of rows) with some fields, let's say : Field1, Field2, Field3 and Field4.
Before, the Field4 was a nullable field. And the value was never filled.
There is some indexes created using this field.

The idea is to update this field to have a specific int value X.
But doing that can cause multiple problem :

- Updating the rows will put a lock on those rows. I can make update 100 per 100 and make a sleep between the update to avoid locks being created.
  I don't know yet how I'll do that. So if you have idea, feel free to share.
- The indexes will be rebuilt... This can cause some longer time processing.

I thought there are other ways to achieve what I want :

- Create an additional field (Field5), that is a duplicate of Field4 but with the specified value. Then make a swap of the fields.
  But I don't know how much time the swapping will take, if the indexes will be impacted, ...
- Making a dirty Update (with nolock). But I've seen that it's deprecated because it can break indexes.

This table is on production and thus, we want to avoid any problem.
And furthermore, we have other tables that have this fields that need to be updated..

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Columns, not fields...

Comment: It is stated you want to avoid locks, and so implied that your production server is 'busy', however you define that. But I have to ask for the sake of clarity, is it really not possible to probably save yourself some trouble and have brief maintenance downtime at an off-peak time to take care of this, locks and all?

Comment: When you say millions, how many millions, because I'd say just update - but of course there might be info not given that prevent that. Shouldn't take terrible long to just insert 0 (or something) unless additional logic needs to be there.

Comment: @Thernys : We cannot afford a downtime right now. So if we could do it without it would be great

Comment: I think you are overestimating .Index rebuild if build online takes locks only during initial and end phases.you also need to provide more specific info on table schema ,data count,number of DML per day for some one to answer more specifically

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen : 17 millions. And there is not only this table, there are other that have the same "problem". So in total, i would say hundreds of millions of rows to update. With multiple indexes refering to this column.

Comment: `NOLOCK` is ignored for the target table of an update. The update will need to take a lock, always, otherwise it couldn't guarantee atomicity, so you can scratch that one as an option. (You can make the "select" portion of an update operate under `READ UNCOMMITTED`, but that's not going to help you much in this case since you have to update all rows.)

Comment: The question is too common so no clear answer can be given IMHO. Based on what you say I would SELECT TOP 10000 of records WHERE intfield IS NULL, update those based on what goal I have, wait a little and pick the next 10K (or 100K or 1M or 1K only, "depends"...). Your idea of adding an extra field, and manipulate that is also cool. In some cases, making a copy of the table, manipulate it, load back and swap out tables can also work (1sec "downtime"), so again, "depends"...